# Flash Builder Flex Sqlite database recover

Tags: ipad, flash, apache-flex, sqlite, builder

Got a question that i can seem to find an answer.
I'm creating a simple mobile application (iPad only for now) which use a simple sqlite Database.
I'm working with sqlite locally since i really don't want to force the use of Wireless in the application.

My question is, is there any way to recover the data inserted in app?
Sqlite as the dump to txt file can i use this to recover data? 
Can i upload the sqlite file to a website or send it to an email?

Can this be done by any method?

Ty in advance :)

Comment: It help in some way, but my main issue is how to take the data out, for instance, from an iPad. I would like to get one button in my application that could create that dump and then take it out from the ipad by email or something like that.

thank you :)